# Validation in jsp page

Tags: java, jsp

I am using a form where i  am adding an state into the database  but now i want to use a server side validation for this form (like checking whether it is empty or not.) So please help me in this. 
By the way i am new in jsp and want to learn server side validation in jsp page so plese let me know how to go about it.

```
    String sql="insert into tblstate(fkCountry_Id,fldstate) "
            + "values('"+cou+"','"+sta+"')";
    try{
      conn.createStatement().executeUpdate(sql);
      conn.setAutoCommit(true);
      // New location to be redirected

    String site = new String("add_state.htm");
    response.setStatus(response.SC_MOVED_TEMPORARILY);
    response.setHeader("Location", site);

    }catch(Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
%>
" method="POST">
                            <div class="control-group">
                                <label class="control-label" for="selectError">Country</label>
                                    <select class="form-control" name="cou">
                                        <option value="none">Select</option>
                                        <%
                                        String sql_cou = "select * from tblcountry";
                                        PreparedStatement coun=conn.prepareStatement(sql_cou);
                                        ResultSet rs_cou = coun.executeQuery(sql_cou);
                                        while(rs_cou.next()){
                                            out.println("<option value=" + rs_cou.getString("pkCountry_Id")+ "> " + rs_cou.getString("fldCountry")+"</option>");                                           
                                        }
                                        %>
                                    </select> 
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">State</label>
                                <input name="sta" type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter Dzongkhag">
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
```

Comment: JSPs should not do validation, and even less communicate with a database. JSPs are view components, used to generate HTML from Java Beans stored in request attributes, using the JSP EL, the JSTL and other custom tags. They should not contain any Java code. The validation and data retrieval should be done in Java from a Servlet.

Comment: Thank you but in that case how to validate form using servlet and where to put the above java code. Please help me with an example so that i can have a clear picture.